# What is the effective way to do a lot of SOAP request?

Tags: php, soap

I have a server on AWS, and I used php as the backend language.

Because of connecting to some API, I have to do some task via SOAP, maybe 20000 queries in 5 minutes or less.I decided to split the task into two part..
part 1.generate request and save into mysql db.
part 2.write a program which fetch one row from db and send a SOAP request.

But I don't know how to do part2?
If I make a php file and execute per second, will my server be very slow?
What is the best way to do "keep fetching data from db and sending a SOAP request"? Write one program use "while loop"(keep fetching data from db) or execute one program per second(just fetch one row)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to read about Beanstalkd and Pheanstalk (https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk).
It will be much faster than keep connecting & fetching queries, and you won't exhaust the database, since Beanstalkd is stored in the RAM memory.

Read more:

- http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2014/working-with-php-and-beanstalkd
- http://dev.af83.com/2013/03/13/why-you-should-consider-beanstalkd.html